# I have upgraded serenity version to 4.0.1 . After that even if Test is failed it is showing as passed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-serenity

I have upgraded serenity version to `4.0.1` . After upgrade even if Test is failed it is showing as passed.
Below are the config

```
slf4jVersion = '2.0.9'
serenityCoreVersion = '4.0.1'
serenityCucumberVersion = '4.0.1'
serenityRestAssuredVersion = '4.0.1'
junitVersion = '4.13.1'
assertJVersion = '3.8.0'
logbackVersion = '1.4.11'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10b7X.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAiIK.png)
Before upgrade tests were working correctly. Not sure what is missing.